# Error in phpmysql database connectivity

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require 'database.inc.php';
$query="SELECT 'food','calorie' FROM 'users' ORDER BY 'id' " ;
if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
{echo '<br> working';}
else {echo '<br>nothing error';
echo mysql_error();}   ?>
```

ERROR:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'

Comment: You cannot use quotes in table name or field name. Please remove it.
`$query="SELECT food,calorie FROM users ORDER BY id " ;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your ' with `(this is the sign below ~ in keyboard) as:

```
$query="SELECT `food`,`calorie` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id`";
```

Comment: r u from dalal fertilizers

Answer (score 0):

Delete all single quotes `'` in your query :

```
$query="SELECT food,calorie FROM users ORDER BY id";
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the quotes for table name or field name. instead use back quotes if needed (`).

For normal field names it is not mandatory. if table contain any field name, that is a mysql key name, it is mandatory.
for eg:- if column name "group" exists. with out back quotes it will throw error.

```
$query="SELECT `food`,`calorie` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` " ;
```